# Find the key existence in JSON object

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a JSON string

```
String str = '{ "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }'
```

In the above string, **city** is an optional key and may not be present in the JSON data.

I decoded the json string

```
var jsonResponse = json.decode(str);
```

I want to get to know the existence of **city** key the **jsonResponse** object.

Answer (score 45):

`jsonResponse.containsKey("key");`

Answer (score 11):

I am not sure how good is the solution, but it is working.

```
String str = '{ "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }';
Map<String, String> jsonResponse = json.decode(str);

if (jsonResponse.containsKey('city')){
   // do your work
}
```

Instead of capturing the JSON object in **var**,  capture it into a

```
Map<String, String>
or 
Map<String, Object> //if value is again an object
```

Comment: In Dart 2, you cannot assign the result of parsing a JSON object to a `Map<String, String>`. The value is always a `Map<String, dynamic>` which is not assignable to `Map<String, String>` any more.

Comment: Map<String, dynamic> is also fine, that serve my purpose  (test the existence of key).

Answer (score 6):

The result of `json.decode` is a `Map<String, dynamic>` with an entry for each key/value pair in the source.

As a `Map`, you can test for the presence of a key using [Map.containsKey](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/Map/containsKey.html). You can also just do a lookup using the `"city"` key and see if you get `null` back. In some cases it's more convenient to just use the `null` value directly than to do an extra check on whether there is something, but that depends entirely on what you are trying to do.

```
var map = jsonDecode(str);
bool containsCity = map.containsKey("city");
String city = map["city"];
if (city == null) // no city ... 
// Use the null directly if you just replace it with a default.
print("${map["name"]} from ${map["city"] ?? "somewhere"}");
// Use a test if you want to do something different if it's there.
print(map["name"] + (city != null ? " from $city" : "");
```

The `map["city"] == null` test differs from `map.containsKey("city")` in the case where your original source contained the pair `"city": null`. You need to decide whether that ever happens, and if it does, how you want to treat it. In many cases, it's probably an error, and should be treated as if there was no `"city"` entry, so I'll usually prefer to use the `map["city"] == null` test over `map.containsKey("city")`.

Answer (score 4):

If your json is simple single-level like your example, you can check it directly with the map like this:

```
String str = '{ "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }';
var jsonResponse = json.decode(str); 
print('City is ${jsonResponse["city"] ?? "empty"}');
```

UPDATE: Thanks [lrn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2156621/lrn). I applied your suggestion.

Comment: You can use the shorter `${jsonResponse["city"] ?? "empty"}` to avoid doing two lookups.