# Is there a Dart function to check if an object has a particular attribute or method?

Tags: flutter, dart

Problems:

i) When checking if the normal Class object in **Dart** has particular property?

ii) When decoding JSON response body from api, How to check if an object has particular properties in **DART**?

e.g. In Javascript, there is "*hasOwnProperty*"

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty('property')) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 22):

You can use `bool containsKey(Object key);`. Checkout [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Map/containsKey.html) for more information. Also here you can find a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596110/find-the-key-existence-in-json-object).

```dart
if (obj.containsKey('property')) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes this is very useful while decoding json response.

But I also meant in normal Class objects in Dart. 
In python, I think we have **hasattr()**

Comment: Yes, but since you asked about JSON response body i did not think about [PODO](https://maxhorstmann.net/blog/2013/09/22/plain-old-dart-objects/).

Comment: But it was helpful. Thank you !!  I think I should correct my question a bit

Answer (score 11):

Dart is strongly typed; you should check if the `Object` is of the type you want before calling methods on it:

```dart
if (obj is ClassWithProperty) {
  print(obj.property);
}
```

I would *not* recommend it, but you could disable type-checking by using a `dynamic` type:

```dart
var hasProperty = false;
try {
  (obj as dynamic).property;
  hasProperty = true;
} on NoSuchMethodError {
}
```

but [catching `Error` types is frowned upon](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-explicitly-catch-error-or-types-that-implement-it).

Comment: How to check if object is a map (regardless of types of its key/values i.e. <String, String>)? The is operator seems to return type with <> which makes it different type.

Comment: @MuhammadQasim You can check if an object is a `Map` via `object is Map` (which is shorthand for `object is Map<dynamic, dynamic>`).

Comment: Ah my bad. Just realized I was comparing the `runtimeType` instead of object itself which was giving false like this:
`var obj = {"abc": 123}; if(obj.runtimeType is Map)`
Thanks for helping.

Comment: unfortunatly the first solution is not always working in Dart.

Comment: @MwBakker Please elaborate.  The first method should work.  You should ensure that you use `is` on a *local* variable since only local variables are automatically type-promoted.

Comment: "You should ensure that you use is on a local variable"  - which explains why I had to force cast in my scenario. Thank you