# Flutter Apps can't responsive with changed / addition response key:value from server into model data

Tags: flutter, dart

i got an issue when an server got updated key value (for example in response API. it have addition key "voucher" that didn't available from oldest response server). But, when implemented with

```
DataModel model = DataModel.fromJson(result['result']);
```

it give crash when get updated value from server when it addition. Can you resolve it with any solution if server give an updated without addition model in flutter apps?

Edit : After request many response in comment such like @AhmedAshour and @Davidn . so that, i give an error in my case

```
Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value
```

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? Showing the error message helps better.

You could also try: `DataModel.fromJson(result['result'] as Map<String, dynamic>);`

Comment: Please provide the code for `DataModel.fromJson`, the result of `print(result);` and the error message.

Comment: thx u very much. i reply it after this.

Comment: sorry for keep waiting. now, i can't give it because of my office server got down. so that, i can spending time in tomorrow if i can. thx u for helped me @Ah

Comment: Then cast it as a `String` instead of `Map<String, dynamic>`

Comment: Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast -> sometimes i try to use .toString after json.decode(result) or result['result']. but it give an error because string can't work with Map<String,dynamic> even i try used .toString() instead Map<String,dynamic>

Comment: What type are you getting from your jsondecode, is it a `Map` or a `List`. Knowing what type helps you assign the right data type.

See: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: {“total_data”:”10”,”result”:[ {“name:”tester01”,”address:”tester02 No. 25”}]} -> i created model data json sometimes similar like it @davidn. sorry if i make a dummy json model data because a real data case is forbidden. but, there's a result was Map and after then, list

Comment: Then do: `List result = jsonDecode(something)[result];` followed by `...fromJson(result as Map<String, dynamic> )`. What you get from your jsondecode is of type `Map` but  what you need there is `result` which is of type `List<Map>`

Comment: because of i want to get an result that same as an value of json response key.

Comment: anyway after i ask this case with my friend in office. i have resolved this solution by this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596110/find-the-key-existence-in-json-object @davidn. it will be helped when check in json response key is exist or nothing. thx u for helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway after i ask this case with my friend in office. i have resolved this solution by this

[Find the key existence in JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596110/find-the-key-existence-in-json-object)

because it helped when checked a json response key is exist or nothing. so i make like this in my model

```
factory DataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DataModel(
    name: json.containsKey(“name”) ? json[“name”] != null ? json[“name”] : “” : “”);
```